# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException with substring

Tags: java, android

This is my code:

```
String s = word;
String[] split = s.split(Dictionary.searchTerm);
String s1 = split[0];
String s2 = split[1];
String cut1 = "...";
String cut2 = s2.substring(0, 20);
```

I get `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=17; regionStart=0; regionLength=20` caused by the line `String cut2 = s2.substring(0, 20);`

What I'm trying to do is, for example, this is the original string `s`

Google
Android
Gmail
Youtube
Apple
iOS
Mac
Microsoft
Windows

The `searchTerm` is Youtube, so the desired string is

...Youtube Apple

How to solve this? Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to replace the string before the searchTerm to ... and to add on partial part of string after the searchTerm.

Comment: `String cut1 = s1.replace(s1, "...");` is same as `String cut1 = "...";`. What are you trying to do in this line? Also please put proper values in your code example. Instead of saying that `s` is some text put it in code `s = "some text..";`. Same about `Dictionary.searchTerm`.

Comment: Sorry. Just want to ask, how do searchTerm relate to the desired string actually.

Comment: string `s` is actually a data from a column in my Sqlite database. `Dictionary.searchTerm` is the text user enter at search bar. It is changing dynamically and is attached to TextChangedListener

Comment: Yes, we understand that, but to make your example simpler it is better to fill it with proper values so we could copy-paste it to our IDEs and work on it. Take your time and create example which will let us and future readers easily reproduce your problem.

Comment: Anyway your error is clear. In `s2.substring(0, 20);` you are trying to subtract first 20 characters, but `s2` holds string with only 17 characters. What is your expected result here?

Comment: Please post your requirements clearly that what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to replace the string before the searchTerm to ... and to add on partial part of string after the searchTerm.

Comment: Could you define "partial part of string after the searchTerm"? Are you searching for only one word, or exact 20 characters? What would you like to do if there are no 20 characters like in this case?

Comment: @user2872856 Edited my answer, give it a try.

Comment: Like the example in my question, the "partial part of string after the searchTerm", Youtube is Apple iOS Mac. I would like to let user see what are the content after the searchTerm. It can be any number of character after the searcTerm. If there are no 20 character, then just show what the remain contains.

Comment: Can we assume that all names will always be one word? Or can there be names like "American Express"? In that case if first part of that name is within 20 characters, but second is outside of 20 range, what should be result?

Comment: Doesn't matter, I just want to show something after the searchTerm, it doesn't need to be a complete word. It can be Youtube Appl

Comment: In that case `String cut2 = s2.substring(0, Math.min(20, s2.length()));` should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement can be achieved by the following code, not tested tough.

```
    String s = "Google     Android    Gmail    Youtube     Apple    iOS     Mac     Microsoft   Hewlett packard      Windows";

            String[] keywords = s.split("\\s+");

            String searchTerm = "Youtube";

            String endText = "";

            for(int index = 0; index < keywords.length; index++) {
                if(keywords[index].contentEquals(searchTerm)) {
                    if(index != (keywords.length - 1)) {
                        endText = endText + "..." + " " + searchTerm + " " + keywords[index + 1];
                    } else {
                        endText = endText + "..." + " " + searchTerm + " " + keywords[0];
                    }
                }
            }

// Here the endText would be: "... Youtube Apple"
```

Comment: String endText =  ""; is just an initialization of a string that holds the value for the string to be set. You can post your code of how you are doing setText, because I've tested the code and it's working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, it is working if I put the raw data in java code, i.e. Google\n" + "Android\n". Just the problem is, the string s is from sqlite database and the text is saved without the \n character. But in the sqlite database, Google, Android, etc all are separated with new line.

Comment: What is the string you are getting from sqlite database, are you getting all of your keywords as a separate string? If yes, then there will be no need to create an array by using split function, you can just create an arraylist and add strings from your database into list, and then use that list as the same way we have used array here.

Comment: The string in sqlite database is as in my question, Google Android till Windows in single string. There is no \n character. I use DB Browser and press return to make a new line.

Comment: In that case you can split the string using s.replaceAll("\\s+", " "); and then s.split(" "), if all the keywords are of single word without space.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Actually there is space for some my data in the single line, i.e some of my data has more than one word in single line. So that I think we can use `String[] keywords = s.split("\\s+");` But then how to work on `endText`?

Comment: No you can't use s.split("\\s+") because that will also separate out your single keyword with two words as a different keywords. I think you should restructure your db table and add different keywords in different row.

Comment: It's doesn't matter to separate single keyword with 2 words as a different keywords. Can you please let me know how to work on endtext? It's almost to achieve what I want using your method.

Comment: We should find for content which equal to keyword, then add "..." in front and add the next keyword after.

Comment: Edited the answer, that will work. Consider to accept it if helped.

Answer (score 0):

The StringOutOfBoundsException is being thrown because you're assuming that cut2 ends at index 20, and your string is not that long. Instead of hard-coding 20 you'll want to calculate the length of `s2`. And if you're expecting `s2` to be of length 21, you probably want to check to make sure it's storing what you think it's storing.